# backbone model.save() does not set the response body of the express server with body parser

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, express, backbone-model, body-parser

I am trying to save (post) a Backbone model using a model.save().

Model:

```
Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: '/project/',
  defaults: {
    projectname: "default projectname"
 }
});
```

Saving the model (in my Backbone.router object):

```
putTest: function(id) {
    var projectItem = new ProjectModel({projectname: "This shiny new project"});
    projectItem.save();
},
```

I would expect my node/express router on the server, which uses the middleware 'body-parser', to get the attributes of the model on the express request.body object, like so:

```
post: function(request, response) {
        console.log(request.body.projectname);
}
```

but the response.body object is empty.

When I am using a regular html form with method="post" like so:

```
<form id =  "createProject"
  action    =  "/project/"
  method    =  "post" >
  <input type="text" name="projectName" value="Project name" />
</form>
```

everything is working as expected.

I have struggled with this the whole day now, and can't see what I am doing wrong.

Have I misunderstood the whole Backbone.model.save() concept or is there an other object on the express request object that holds the attributes of my Backbone model when saving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, an HTML `<form>` sends `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data and no JSON like `Backbone.sync()` does (that's used by `.save()` internally).

Open your browser's developer tools and take a look in the network analysis when saving the model to make sure the **request** works correctly (JSON Body, URL, ...).

However, since your backend handles form data correctly, I'd guess your middleware is not configured in the way you want it to.

Comment: Thx for your answer. It led me in the right direction. My body-parser was set to using url encoding ( app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); ) instead of json( app.use(bodyParser.json(); ). My lack of experience with middleware never made me think of that possibility even. Thx again.